# Solution for composite events with Apache Kafka?

Tags: events, apache-kafka

Architecture question: We have an Apache Kafka based eventing system and multiple systems producing / sending events. Each event has some data including an ID and I need to implement a "ID is complete"-event. Example:

`Event_A(id)
Event_B(id)
Event_C(id)`

are received asynchonrously, and only once all 3 events are received, I need to send a `Event_Complete(id)`. The problem is that we have multiple clusters of consumers and our database is eventual consistent.

A simple way would be to use the eventually consistent DB to store which events we have for each ID and add a "cron" job to catch race conditions eventually.

It feels like a problem that might have been solved out there already. So my question is, is there a better way to do it (without introducing a consistent datastore to the picture)?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Several consumers may receive the same event with the same id?

Comment: consumers are in the same Kafka consumer-group, so each event is only received by one consumer as far as I understand.